# "Closed Explicitly" mgo MongoDB in Go

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have a Docker cluster running 10 web services (of the same kind). They are all using MongoDB, among other things for data persistence.

This is the code that gets called from `main()`, when the service is booting up:

```
// Init establishes a connection with MongoDB instance.
func Init(mongoURL string) *mgo.Session {
    mongo, err := mgo.Dial(mongoURL)
    misc.PanicIf(err)

    // make sure we are strongly consistent
    mongo.SetMode(mgo.Strong, true)

    // update global state
    db = mongo
    Entries = db.DB("").C("entries")
    Channels = db.DB("").C("channels")
    Settings = db.DB("").C("settings")
    Metadata = db.DB("").C("metadata")

    // only use this on first load, to confirm the settings are there
    // every refresh should be done via UpdateGlobalSettings (thread-safe)
    GlobalSettings = &GlobalSettingsStruct{}
    GlobalSettings.Init()

    return mongo
}
```

So basically the API and the workers just use global variables such as `Entries`, `Settings`, etc.

After running for a while, the service stopped working properly. Every mongo action, such as `Entries.find(...)` returns an err of: `Closed Explicitly`.

What does that mean? Should I be refreshing the mongoDB connection periodically or should I make it close and re-establish connection with each request?

The app is performance oriented, so despite mongo connection being down, everything is still up and running as everything operates on in-memory or cluster cache. I don't want to do something stupid that delays processing.

Answer (score 0):

that is ok. but to use `Session.Copy` to create a new connection instance, instead of using the returned session directly. there are connection pool inside golang mongodb driver package.

Answer (score 0):

When `sess.SetPoolLimit(50)` not used many errors are occurring when `mgo` is under stress like 10.000 concurrent connections.

When I limit the pool errors went away.

I've created a test-case source-code for this problem below, so you can test it in your own machine easily.

Do you have any suggestions about this behaviour, I would like to hear.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    // you can also use original go-mgo/mgo here as well
    mgo "github.com/globalsign/mgo"
    "github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson"
)

// TODO: put some records into db first:
//
// use testapi
// db.competitions.insert([
//   {game_id: 1, game_name: "foo"},
//   {game_id: 2, game_name: "bar"},
//   {game_id: 3, game_name: "jazz"}
// ])

// NOTE: you might want to increase this depending on your machine power
//       mine is:
//         MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2015)
//         1,2 GHz Intel Core M
//         8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
const ops = 10000

type m bson.M

func main() {
    sess, err := mgo.DialWithTimeout("localhost", time.Second)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer sess.Close()

    // NOTE: without this setting there are many errors
    //       see the end of the file
    // setting pool limit prevents most of the timeouts
    // sess.SetPoolLimit(50)

    // sess.SetSocketTimeout(60 * time.Second)
    sess.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    done := make(chan bool, ops)

    for i := 0; i < ops; i++ {
        go func() {
            defer func() { done <- true }()

            result, err := fetchSomething(sess)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("ERR: %s\n", err)
            }
            fmt.Printf("RESULT: %+v\n", result)
        }()
    }

    for i := 0; i < ops; i++ {
        <-done
    }
}

func fetchSomething(sess *mgo.Session) ([]m, error) {
    s := sess.Copy()
    defer s.Close()

    result := []m{}

    group := m{
        "$group": m{
            "_id": m{
                "id":   "$game_id",
                "name": "$game_name",
            },
        },
    }

    project := m{
        "$project": m{
            "_id":  "$_id.id",
            "name": "$_id.name",
        },
    }

    sort := m{
        "$sort": m{
            "_id": 1,
        },
    }

    err := col(s, "competitions").Pipe([]m{group, project, sort}).All(&result)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return result, nil
}

// col is a helper for selecting a column
func col(sess *mgo.Session, name string) *mgo.Collection {
    return sess.DB("testapi").C(name)
}

/*


ERRORS WITHOUT sess.SetPoolLimit(50)


$ go run socket_error.go
RESULT: [map[name:foo _id:1] map[_id:2 name:bar] map[_id:3 name:jazz]]
ERR: read tcp 127.0.0.1:52918->127.0.0.1:27017: read: connection reset by peer
ERR: write tcp 127.0.0.1:52084->127.0.0.1:27017: write: broken pipe
RESULT: []
RESULT: []
ERR: write tcp 127.0.0.1:53627->127.0.0.1:27017: write: broken pipe
ERR: write tcp 127.0.0.1:53627->127.0.0.1:27017: write: broken pipe
RESULT: []
ERR: write tcp 127.0.0.1:53627->127.0.0.1:27017: write: broken pipe
RESULT: []
ERR: write tcp 127.0.0.1:53627->127.0.0.1:27017: write: broken pipe
RESULT: []
ERR: write tcp 127.0.0.1:53627->127.0.0.1:27017: write: broken pipe
RESULT: []
ERR: write tcp 127.0.0.1:53627->127.0.0.1:27017: write: broken pipe
RESULT: []
RESULT: []
ERR: read tcp 127.0.0.1:53627->127.0.0.1:27017: read: connection reset by peer
RESULT: []
ERR: resetNonce: write tcp 127.0.0.1:53625->127.0.0.1:27017: write: broken pipe
RESULT: []
RESULT: [map[name:foo _id:1] map[_id:2 name:bar] map[_id:3 name:jazz]]
ERR: resetNonce: write tcp 127.0.0.1:54591->127.0.0.1:27017: write: broken pipe
RESULT: []
...
...
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all try enabling debug mode in mgo in order to get some more info about what's happening.

I suppose the server is dropping the connection after some inactivity time.
In any case, usually the approach is to do a mgo `Dial` and then `Copy` the connection at the beginning of every request handling(using a middleware).

Pietro